# NextAuth.js + Auth0: offline_access breaks jwt decryption

Tags: javascript, next.js, auth0, next-auth

I'm trying to implement next-auth with Auth0 provider to an existing application.
Everything works fine, but when I try to add the offline_access scope to retrieve a refresh token, the application randomly crashes after a few seconds:

```
https://next-auth.js.org/warnings#no_secret
[next-auth][error][JWT_SESSION_ERROR]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#jwt_session_error decryption operation failed {
  message: 'decryption operation failed',
  stack: 'JWEDecryptionFailed: decryption operation failed\n' +
    '    at gcmDecrypt (my_path/node_modules/jose/dist/node/cjs/runtime/decrypt.js:67:15)\n' +
    '    at decrypt (my_path/node_modules/jose/dist/node/cjs/runtime/decrypt.js:92:20)\n' +
    '    at flattenedDecrypt (my_path/node_modules/jose/dist/node/cjs/jwe/flattened/decrypt.js:119:52)\n' +
    '    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)\n' +
    '    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)\n' +
    '    at async compactDecrypt (my_path/node_modules/jose/dist/node/cjs/jwe/compact/decrypt.js:18:23)\n' +
    '    at async jwtDecrypt (my_path/node_modules/jose/dist/node/cjs/jwt/decrypt.js:8:23)\n' +
    '    at async Object.decode (my_path/node_modules/next-auth/jwt/index.js:62:7)\n' +
    '    at async Object.session (my_path/node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/session.js:41:28)\n' +
    '    at async NextAuthHandler (my_path/node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:96:27)\n' +
    '    at async NextAuthNextHandler (my_path/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:20:19)\n' +
    '    at async my_path/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:56:32\n' +
    '    at async apiResolver (my_path/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/api-utils.js:8:1)\n' +
    '    at async DevServer.handleApiRequest (my_path/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:64:462)\n' +
    '    at async Object.fn (my_path/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:56:492)\n' +
    '    at async Router.execute (my_path/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/router.js:23:67)',
  name: 'JWEDecryptionFailed'
}
```

I'm not even trying to do anything with the refresh token at the moment, just changing the scopes.
When reverting to the default scopes everything works fine again.

Here's my code:

```js
export default NextAuth({
    // Configure one or more authentication providers
    providers: [
      Auth0Provider({
        clientId: CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
        issuer: ISSUER,
        idToken: true,
        // authorization: {params: {scope: 'openid email profile offline_access'}},
      }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
      async signIn({profile}) {
        // Sentry.setUser(...)
        return true
      },
      async redirect({baseUrl}) {
        return baseUrl
      },
      async jwt({token, account, profile}) {
        if (account) {
          token.accessToken = account.id_token
        }
        if (profile) {
          token.profile = profile['https://my-company-oauth-profile-path/']
        }
  
        return token
      },
      async session({session, token}) {
        session.accessToken = token.accessToken
        session.profile = token.profile
        return session
      },
    },
    pages: {
      signIn: '/auth/signin',
    },
    debug: true,
})
```

My next-auth version is "4.1.2".

Answer (score 4):

For anyone struggling with something similar:

https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#secret

> *The default behaviour is volatile*, and it is strongly recommended you explicitly specify a value [for the secret option]. If secret is omitted in production, an error is thrown.